# Ajax POST insert half data(some data is missed) Asp.Net MVC Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am inserting data via Ajax Post method. Data is inserted in one table but the data for secod table is not inserting. I have checked the code but I am not sure that what is mising in my code.

When I use the direct controller method then the data is inserted in both table but when I use the Ajax then data is inserted in only one table.

**My Old working Controller code:**

```
[HttpPost]
         public ActionResult Create(StudentModel model)
         {
             if(ModelState.IsValid)
             {
                 int id = stude.AddStudent(model);
                 if(id>0)
                 {
                     ModelState.Clear();
                     ViewBag.Success = "Data added Successfully";
                   
               }
             }
             return View();
         }
```

**My Ajax Controller Code:**

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Creates(StudentModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                int id = stude.AddStudent(model);
                if (id > 0)
                {
                    ModelState.Clear();
                    ViewBag.Success = "Data added Successfully";
                    return Json("success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }

            return Json("issue", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**My Model Code:**

```
public int AddStudent(StudentModel stu)
        {
            student stud = new student()
            {
                FName = stu.FName,
                LName = stu.LName,
                Email = stu.Email

            };
            if (stu.address != null) {
                stud.address= new address()
                {
                    Details = stu.address.Details,
                    Country = stu.address.Country,
                    State = stu.address.State

                };
            }
            using (var context = new StudentEntities())
            {
                    context.students.Add(stud);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
                    
                
               
                return stud.Id;
            
        }
```

**My Js/Ajax Code:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            //Add record
            $("#add").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                // var id = $();
                var fname = $("#FName").val();
                var lname = $("#LName").val();
                var email = $("#Email").val();
                var details = $("#Details").val();
                var country = $("#Country").val();
                var state = $("#State").val();


                $.ajax({
                    async: true,
                    method: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("Creates")',
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        FName: fname, LName: lname, Email: email, Details: details,County: country, State: state
                    }),
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        //window.location = data.newurl;
                        console.log(data);

                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        alert('Failed to get data' + err);
                    }
                });
                return false;

            });
});
```

Data is inserted in only student table and for the address table it returns null/empty and the data is skipped, although the same code will work if I remove the Ajax. But I want to use the Ajax so things will work smoothly.

Any help will be appreciated.

**Update: Student Model class:**

I am using N-Tire/3-Tire Architecture

**My Student class Properties**

```
 public class StudentModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AddressId { get; set; }

    public AddressModel address { get; set; }
}
```

**My Address Class Properties**

```
 public class AddressModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Details { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post StudentModel , Student and Address classes pls?

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: thanks, but I guess you have a Student and Addresses classes too?

Comment: the data insertion issue is almost handled but now I am not getting the success message, which I set in my viewbag. you can see it in the above controller code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There were a lot of issues in my code. I am listing it below.

1. The main, which I think case the problem is the Id's of my textboxes, as I am using Razor Engine and it creates the id automatic, which cause the issue, So I fix it by adding the Id and Name manually, like

   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.address.Details, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", Name="Details", Id="Details"} })
2. I have changed my ajax data code to:

   FName: fname, LName: lname, Email: email, address: { Details: details, Country: country, State: state }
3. For success message I have change Return message in my controller like:

   var scess = "Data added Successfully";
   return Json(new { success = true, scess }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

and in my view I have add this line in my ajax success call:

```
 success: function (data) {
                       
                        $("#msg").text(data.scess);
                        console.log(data);

                    },
```

Hope this will also help other users in future.